# How to insert SQL Server geometry data to postgis geometry data type column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

We have data in our SQL Server of `geometry` datatype.

When doing

```
select shape 
from boundary_polygon
```

I get this result:

[image]

I have exported the data from SQL Server from the table shown here. How can I import the same data into postgres with datatype `geometry` for the below is the table structure. As the data in the `shape` column is in hexadecimal, how to import?

```
create table boundary_polygon(id int, shape geometry)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geometry` in sql server is a blob in the CLR Type Serialization Format.

read more about that in [Microsoft SQL Server CLR Types Serialization Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssclrt/77460aa9-8c2f-4449-a65e-1d649ebd77fa)

whereas postgis uses WKB (well known binary) for it's geometry datatype.

in sql server you can convert that format into WKT (well known text) by using `STAsText()` method.
read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stastext-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

so convert your data in sql server to KWT :

```
select shape.STAsText() 
from boundary_polygon
```

now you can easily insert them in postgis geometry.